# Physics and Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, learning

Currently I have asked to me if physics is needed to study differential geometry. I know that in the theory, we can study differential geometry without any concept of physics; however, so many ideas in differential geometry has arose from physics, which lead me to think that, if I study differential geometry but I don't know anything about physics (for instance, relativity) then I will repeat theorems like a parrot, because I don't have a motivation of a problem.

I would like to know that it is not the case.

PD. (I'm sorry for my english, it is not my native language)

Comment: A large part of differential geometry has not much to do with physics. Even if you work in (e.g.) mirror symmetry, (mathematical) general relativity, you don't need to know much about physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any physics to learn differential geometry.  It definitely helps to know a little, but it's not essential.